# Programs scroll by themselves, and in terminal certain text appears by itself ~~~~~

Tags: gnome, gui, bug-reporting, scrolling

I recently upgrade GNOME and certain things started happening:

1. In any window that can scroll, after a certain amount of time scrolling down happens by itself, even if I try to scroll up again it will scroll down non-stop. It happens with Firefox, PDF viewer, etc, in any program or place where scroll down is possible.
2. In terminal characters like ~~~~~ or [^6~ (if a press shift) will appear, some of the times they appear faster one after the other, other times they appear slower. And I need to push a key to stop it, but sometimes it will start again right away, making it impossible to write any commands in the terminal.
3. Also one out of two times that I turn on my laptop, the ctrl key command doesn't work, nor the shift key, so I can't do ctrl+copy/paste/cut, I can't activate the special characters, and I can't either write capital letters doing shift+letter. In some cases, the special function key doesn't work either, so I can't adjust the volume or the screen brightness using the keyboard.

My machine is single-boot, I have Ubuntu 19.10, I don't use any external keyboard or mouse, so I suppose the problem is internal. I have a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you try with a live Ubuntu USB (preferably 20.04)?

Comment: Looks like a faulty keyboard...